# Why does my first array item always contain 'Function'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to javascript and have been working on modifications to a node js / mongo web service. I'm looping through an array and performing a query with an id at each index so I can get the full object back as shown below:

```
var topicObjArray = [orm.Topic];

for(var i = 0; i < topicIdsArray.length; i++) {

    orm.Topic
        .find({ appId: appId, _id: topic[i].id})
        .exec(function(error, topic) {
        if(error) {
            console.log('oops ' + error);
        }
        else if(topic && topic.length > 0) {
            topicObjArray.push(topic); 
            count++;
        }
        else {
            count++;
        }

        if(count == topicIdsArray.length) {
            // yay we've got all our topics! Carry on!
            // But oh no something is amiss!
        }
    });
}
```

Under normal circumstances the count would increment until it equals the original array count and the method can complete. In this case for some reason at initialization of the topicObjArray the first index is occupied with 'Function' before I even insert any objects. So if I am querying for six objects, I will only ever get back 5 of them, because the first index is always occupied.

I'm sure I must be overlooking something simple here, but a web search rendered no hints to a solution. The problem must be in the initialization of the array, but I don't understand what it is. I've tried different ways of instantiating it with the same result. Here is a screen capture from my debugger that best describes what is happening (I'm using WebStorm IDE):

[image: Weirdness]

Let me know if you need any more information. I appreciate any insight the community can offer.

Comment: That way: `var topicObjArray = [orm.Topic];`

Comment: Is this the exact code, your `for` loop doesn't have an opening brace?

Comment: Yeah the code is lacking the initialization + the variable naming is different than your debug example - the issue is not in the code you've shown.

Comment: @clav: Yeah I left that out by accident. Fixed.

Comment: @ jani: Somehow the initialization code got removed from my post. I'll add it back in. Ignore the differences in the debug example var names.

Comment: I still can't find your `topicsArray` variable, how do you initialize it? Is `topicsArray = topicsObjArray` ? If you initialize your Array with `topicObjArray = [orm.Topic]` it's not an error since your first element is actually an instance method from your orm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initialize the array like this

```
var topicObjArray = [orm.Topic];
```

This makes the first element of the array `orm.Topic`, which judging from the rest of your code is a function.

Simply initialize your array like this instead:

```
var topicObjArray = [];
```

Comment: Thank you. Works flawlessly. So is this the proper way for every type of array, or merely custom objects? Seems like I've initialized other arrays like so: var stringArray = [String].

Comment: There is no typing for arrays in JS, so you always use `[]`. Anything you put between them will become an element in the array, eg. `[String]` would put the `String` object into it and most likely it wouldn't behave like you wanted it to.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Probably most of my growing pains have stemmed from improper initialization. I appreciate the help very much.